# How to access key from its value of object in typescript

Tags: typescript

I was wondering to access & pass the key of an object in typescript.
Here my example:

```
const fruit = {
  apple: true,
  mango: false
}

if(fruit) {
  return fruit.apple; (return value is true)
 // But we are supposed to return the object key whose value turns out to be true
 // means we need to return its key which is 'apple'
}
```

Please help me! How to achieve this. Since I am new to typescript.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is, find get all keys and find which value is true.

```js
const fruit = {
  apple: true,
  mango: false,
};

const returnFruit = (fruit) => {
  if (fruit) {
    const keys = Object.keys(fruit);
    return keys.find((key) => fruit[key]);
  }
  return null;
};

console.log(returnFruit(fruit));
```